# Verifying SSL certificates of a remote web-site

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I have an OpenSSL client (multi-threaded) written in C.
This client connects to a number of HTTPS web-sites, and performs actions like a typical browser.
To ensure that the client is connecting to authentic web-servers I have set it to use a ca-certificates.crt
with the typical    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations (ctx, "ca-certificates.crt" , NULL) method.

To generate the "ca-certificates.crt" file I installed mono / mozroots and did the following:

```
mozroots --pkcs7 moz.p7b
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in moz.p7b -print_certs -out ca-certificates.crt
```

So far things are running as expected, and the use of :

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
```

followed by    SSL_get_verify_result(ssl); produces alerts in case I am connecting to some "unauthentic" HTTPS web-site.

My OpenSSL client currently processes about 100 web-sites parallelly, and with some further optimization, I hope to achieve more

I would like to further optimize my client, so that I can:

1. I think openssl would be invoking some underlying method to do a disk I/O to use "ca-certificates.crt", am I correct?
   Is there a way to load this "ca-certificates.crt" into memory, and using some openssl api to access this memory location? Would it not make my client a bit more faster?
2. How do typical web-browsers access the "Trust Store"? I think they access the "Trust Store" in-memory using some more efficient method? Am I right? Can some-body offer me some good tips here about how?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this great tutorial how to validate a remote SSL certificate: https://github.com/iSECPartners/ssl-conservatory/blob/master/openssl/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-openssl.pdf

There is also a demo application available in the same gitHub repository: https://github.com/iSECPartners/ssl-conservatory/tree/master/openssl

Hope it helps you !

Comment: The links suggested by you are extremely useful and most recommendable for anybody getting ready to start programming with openssl. However they don't really address my issue. :(